# installed "powerbi-visuals-api" version - "undefined"

Tags: powerbi, pbiviz

I have different powerbi-api-versions installed in my project
Any suggestions on how to fix the below error

```
> start
> pbiviz start

 info   powerbi-visuals-tools version - 4.0.3
 warn   "powerbi-visuals-api" is not installed
 warn   installed "powerbi-visuals-api" version - "undefined", is not match with the version specified in pbviz.json - "3.8.0".
 info   Installing API: ~3.8.0...
```